# Resource compilation for C# project

Tags: c#, resource-files

I have a C# project with a great deal of image files in resources. The compilation these resources takes about 30 seconds each time I build the project.

I am wondering if it's possible to configure Visual Studio 2010 to prevent resource compilation if there was no changes in them.

Thanks.

**UPDATED**

Thanks a lot for help. The problem has been solved as follows. 
I changed *persistence* property from «Linked at compile time» to «Embedded in .resx» for all my resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create resource file explicitly and embedded into your assembly.
Moee detail , kindly refer the below link  **[Creating Resource Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbx3z216.aspx)**

Comment: Thanks for the link. It helped me to realize how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio:

- Select all images
- Open properties Windows (F4)
- set `Build Action` to **Content**
- set `Copy to Output Directory` as **Copy if newer**

[image]

Comment: This solution achieves the "only if newer", but changes the resources from being embedded in the dll to being in folders beside the dll.  If this is acceptable, perfect.  Note that since "build" specifically creates the dll anew, and since "embedded resource" sticks things into said dll, there's no such thing as "avoid resource compilation if it didn't change".  There is such a thing as "don't rebuild the dll if nothing here down changed", but that means all files in all dependent projects as well.